# How to change the Image URL of an ImageButton after clicking them based on conditions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton, imageurl

I am working on seating layout for a bus booking system using ASP.NET (C#). I want to allow user to select only one seat in a session.

I have a list of Image buttons. I want that when I click a button then that click event should change its image URL, let's say from "aseat.png" to "sseat.png". But when I click any of the  other buttons then the image URL of the previously clicked button should be back to what it was before and the newly clicked button's image URL should be changed now.

I have created the layout already and when I click on an image button then I am able to change its image URL and change it back again if the same button is clicked, but not been able to make it work like the way I have just described above.

A snippet from my front end code for the layout:

```
<ul class="row1">    
    <li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/aseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat44" ToolTip ="44" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>           
    <li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/aseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat39" ToolTip="39" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>
    <li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/aseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat34" ToolTip="34" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>
    <li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/aseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat29" ToolTip="29" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>
    <li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/aseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat24" ToolTip="24" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>
    <li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/aseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat19" ToolTip="19" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>
    <li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/aseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat14" ToolTip="14" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>
    <li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/aseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat9" ToolTip="9" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>
    <li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/rseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat4" ToolTip="4" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>
    <li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/rseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat1"  ToolTip="1" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>
</ul>
```

C# code:

```
protected void seat1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{   
  ImageButton button = (ImageButton)sender;

  if(button.ImageUrl == "Images/aseat.png")
  {
    button.ImageUrl = "Images/sseat.png";
  }
  else
  {
     button.ImageUrl = "Images/aseat.png";
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="seat._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<ul class="row1" runat="server" id="Seats">
<li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/aseat.png" originalUrl="Images/aseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat44" ToolTip ="44" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>           
<li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/aseat.png" originalUrl="Images/aseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat39" ToolTip="39" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>
<li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/aseat.png" originalUrl="Images/aseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat34" ToolTip="34" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>
<li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/aseat.png" originalUrl="Images/aseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat29" ToolTip="29" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>
<li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/aseat.png" originalUrl="Images/aseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat24" ToolTip="24" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>
<li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/aseat.png" originalUrl="Images/aseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat19" ToolTip="19" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>
<li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/aseat.png" originalUrl="Images/aseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat14" ToolTip="14" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>
<li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/aseat.png" originalUrl="Images/aseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat9" ToolTip="9" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>
<li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/rseat.png" originalUrl="Images/rseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat4" ToolTip="4" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>
<li><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/rseat.png" originalUrl="Images/rseat.png"  OnClick="seat1_Click" ID="seat1"  ToolTip="1" Width="25" Height="25"/></li>
</ul>
</asp:Content>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace seat
{
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
protected void seat1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton button = (ImageButton)sender;
        foreach (var item in Seats.Controls)
        {
            if (item.GetType() == typeof(ImageButton) && ((ImageButton)item).ImageUrl == "Images/sseat.png" && ((ImageButton)item).ID != button.ID)
            { 
                ((ImageButton)item).ImageUrl = ((ImageButton)item).Attributes["originalUrl"];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (button.ImageUrl == "Images/sseat.png")
        {
            button.ImageUrl = button.Attributes["originalUrl"];
        }
        else
        {
            button.ImageUrl = "Images/sseat.png";
        }
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: hi sandeep, thanks for your answer but i wanted to know what does "seats.controls" represents in the foreach loop ? when i tried your code , it gives me an error on that particular line.

Comment: My solution is working. I have tried it. You can check. Let me know if you get any issue.

Comment: Hi sandeep, i tried your code but unfortunately it didn't work for me. I ran the code in debugging mode as well. i could see that after checking the first if condition it's coming out of the loop and not going inside.

Comment: Can you please share your code so that I can help you. Or else, create new project and my filed in without any change.

Comment: Hi sandeep, I tried your code again but this time i created a new page to check it and it really worked. Thanks :)  but i have one more thing to ask , I have more <ul> elements consisiting of other seats. how can i apply that same logic to all the seats ? i can't give every <ul> element the same id right ? i'm attaching my front end of the whole seat layout for you to see.

Comment: Hi sandeep, i'm not able to attach my code here. It says it's too long. can i mail it to you if possible ?

Comment: Hey Sandeep, I made some changes to my front end code and that way i was able to apply the  logic you provided to all the seats. It's working the way i wanted. Thanks, it really helped me. you are awesome :) .

Comment: Done. Thanks again.